# How to properly use setTimeout or setInterval within a Prototype?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a `new Date()` and show the time in a div automatically with a prototype. But it's not working.

## How I wish for it to work

`<div></div>`

```
Element.prototype.startTime

div.startTime('a word')
```

`<div> 00:00:00 </div>` Updates by the second

## What I have

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
}

setTimeout(Element.prototype.startTime = function(t) {
  var today = new Date(),
    h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
    m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
    s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
  if (t === 'time') {
    this.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  }
  if (t === 'minutes') {
    this.innerHTML = m;
  }
  if (t === 'seconds') {
    this.innerHTML = s;
  }
}, 500);// Not Updating Properly

document.getElementById('display').startTime('time');
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

## How it's suppose to work

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
}

function startTime(t) {
  var today = new Date(),
    h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
    m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
    s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());

  div = document.getElementById('display')

  if (t === 'time') {
    div.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  }
  if (t === 'minutes') {
    div.innerHTML = m;
  }
  if (t === 'seconds') {
    div.innerHTML = s;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    startTime(t)
  }, 500);
};
startTime('time');
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: You're not using `setTimeout` *within* the prototype method (as suggested in your title), but around it. That doesn't work. And you [shouldn't use `Element` prototype methods](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) anyway.

Comment: I tried the inside as well… but something still goes wrong

Comment: Your final snippet works fine. Why not just use it? Of course you should make the `div` a parameter of the `startTime` function - like you already have `t` - instead of repeatedly assigning to the global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem for using `setTimeout` in `prototype` was using `this`

So just set `that = this` and use `that` variable… everything will work beautifully.

```js
function checkTime(i) {
  return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
}

Element.prototype.Today = function(t) {
  let that = this
  today = new Date()
  h = checkTime(today.getHours());
  m = checkTime(today.getMinutes());
  s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());

  if (t === 'time') {
    that.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  }
  if (t === 'minutes') {
    that.innerHTML = m;
  }
  if (t === 'seconds') {
    that.innerHTML = s;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.Today(t)
  }, 500);

  return this
};


div = document.getElementById('display')
div.Today('time')
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: You should only use `that` inside the `setTimeout` callback, not everywhere.